# Yosemite Xcode 6.1 build settings crach

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

I am experiencing following crash in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and Xcode 6.1

```
Process:               Xcode [868]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1 (6602)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6602000000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [868]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2014-10-20 14:59:16.731 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        12D310FA-2F8D-CF2C-CD28-355566EFD4EC


Time Awake Since Boot: 78 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052c
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSPopoverFrame _imageMaskForPath:anchorEdge:anchorPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff1ba0bbfc0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8d114634 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
```

Answer (score 14):

My case is because I use a plug-in for Xcode. The name is [Lin](https://github.com/questbeat/Lin-Xcode5). If you are using it, just uninstall the plug-in and Xcode will work just fine! Hope this help you!

This plug-in swizzle the methods draw rect from NSPopoverFrame:

```
[NSPopoverFrame jp_questbeat_lin_drawMinimalPopoverAppearanceInRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg3]
```

I will file bug for the developer to look into it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day.. I was reinstalling Xcode multiple times without any result. :)